# How to install tor on RHEL8

Tags: rhel, repository, tor

I am unable to install tor on RHEL8.1. I create a repository file: `/etc/yum.repos.d/tor.repo` containing

```
[tor]
name=Tor experimental
repo enabled=1 baseurl=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/el/6/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-torproject.org.asc

[tor-source] 
name=Tor experimental source repo 
enabled=1
autorefresh=0 
baseurl=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/el/6/SRPMS
gpgcheck=1 gpgkey=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-torproject.org.asc'
```

When installing tor, I have the following error:

```
# yum -y install tor 
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Tor Project Repo                                                                                                                                962  B/s | 264  B     00:00    
Failed to download metadata for repo 'Tor'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'Tor'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding an incorrect repository for RHEL. RHEL is based on RPM packages, but you are adding a repository with DEB packages for Debian/Ubuntu.

Add repository in file: `/etc/yum.repos.d/tor.repo`

```bsh
[tor]
name=Tor for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=https://rpm.torproject.org/centos/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://rpm.torproject.org/centos/public_gpg.key
cost=100
```

Enable EPEL repository:

```bsh
dnf install epel-release -y
```

Import GPG key for repository:
https://rpm.torproject.org/fedora/public_gpg.key

```bsh
wget -O- -q https://rpm.torproject.org/fedora/public_gpg.key
rpm --import public_gpg.key
```

Install Tor:

```bsh
dnf install tor -y
```

Comment: From the horse's mouth: https://support.torproject.org/rpm/